# Getting BigQuery to auto detect schema

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to load a csv file and have BigQuery automatically create the schema.

```
bq load --source_format CSV -F '\t'  --skip_leading_rows=1 voterdb.voters gs://[[ redacted bucket ]]/extract.csv
BigQuery error in load operation: Error processing job 'tokyo-unity-87516:bqjob_r3682474e46ce720f_0000015421aee065_1': No schema specified on job or table.
```

According to https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/federated-data-sources automatically creating/inferring the schema is supported.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in a previous answer, schema auto-detection is a part of federated data source querying. It is not explicitly stated under the [**CSV and JSON schema auto-detection**](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/federated-data-sources#auto-detect) heading that this does not apply to `bq load`. If you feel this is unclear in the documentation, I would strongly suggest clicking ***Send feedback*** at the top righthand corner of that documentation page and describing this ambiguity in detail.

As for the `bq load` command, according to the [`bq load` documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/bq-command-line-tool#creatingtablefromfile), the table schema is a required parameter. Omitting it does result in the error message you are facing.

**EDIT**
Thanks to polleyg for the update.  In [this blog post](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/03/google-bigquery-cuts-historical-data-storage-cost-in-half-and-accelerates-many-queries-by-10x#automatic-schema-detection), it was announced that the schema should also be detected at load.  As mentioned by Chris Sears, the [`--autodetect`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/bq-command-line-tool#autodetect) flag should meet your needs.

Comment: According to this blog post (https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/03/google-bigquery-cuts-historical-data-storage-cost-in-half-and-accelerates-many-queries-by-10x), auto schema detection supports load too - "This works for CSV, JSON and AVRO at load time"

Comment: This is no longer correct. See my answer regarding `--autodetect`.

Answer (score 6):

The `--autodetect` flag is probably what you want. It works for CSV and (newline delimited) JSON input files.

For example...

```
bq load --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON --autodetect yourdataset.yourtable inputfile.json
```

See documentation here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/bq-command-line-tool#creatingtablefromfile

Note that this has nothing to do with federated data sources.

Answer (score 4):

Here the solution for node js .

```js
const filename = "path of file to be uploaded";
const metadata = {
        sourceFormat: 'CSV',
        skipLeadingRows: 1,
        autodetect: true,
    };
const dataset =await 
bigQuery.dataset('datasetname').table('tablename').load(filename,metadata);
```

Answer (score 2):

Refer GCP document for bigquery schema auto detect
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schema-detect

Sample code from above document

```
 import com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQuery;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryException;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryOptions;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.FormatOptions;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.Job;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.JobInfo;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.LoadJobConfiguration;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.TableId;

// Sample to load JSON data with autodetect schema from Cloud Storage into a new BigQuery table
public class LoadJsonFromGCSAutodetect {

  public static void runLoadJsonFromGCSAutodetect() {
    // TODO(developer): Replace these variables before running the sample.
    String datasetName = "MY_DATASET_NAME";
    String tableName = "MY_TABLE_NAME";
    String sourceUri = "gs://cloud-samples-data/bigquery/us-states/us-states.json";
    loadJsonFromGCSAutodetect(datasetName, tableName, sourceUri);
  }

  public static void loadJsonFromGCSAutodetect(
      String datasetName, String tableName, String sourceUri) {
    try {
      // Initialize client that will be used to send requests. This client only needs to be created
      // once, and can be reused for multiple requests.
      BigQuery bigquery = BigQueryOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();

      TableId tableId = TableId.of(datasetName, tableName);
      LoadJobConfiguration loadConfig =
          LoadJobConfiguration.newBuilder(tableId, sourceUri)
              .setFormatOptions(FormatOptions.json())
              .setAutodetect(true)
              .build();

      // Load data from a GCS JSON file into the table
      Job job = bigquery.create(JobInfo.of(loadConfig));
      // Blocks until this load table job completes its execution, either failing or succeeding.
      job = job.waitFor();
      if (job.isDone()) {
        System.out.println("Json Autodetect from GCS successfully loaded in a table");
      } else {
        System.out.println(
            "BigQuery was unable to load into the table due to an error:"
                + job.getStatus().getError());
      }
    } catch (BigQueryException | InterruptedException e) {
      System.out.println("Column not added during load append \n" + e.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Per link you reference  - BigQuery supports automatic creating/inferring schema when you directly `query` federated data source.
The error you are getting is on `load` from GCS